# React Router v4 dynamic redirect initial load

Tags: reactjs, react-router, electron

I am creating an electron app and I'm not sure the best pattern for handling the following:

The app lets users create a group. So a group route would be `/group/:groupId`. There is no homepage of this app and instead it just defaults to the first available group and displays that. So how do I handle this dynamic redirect to the first group available when the app loads?

In v3 there was an onEnter param that you could set on a route, but I haven't been able to find a pattern for this sort of thing in v4. Any pointers in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Not sure how helpful this is but here are my routes currently:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
<Route path="/group/:groupId" component={GroupPage}>
  <Route path="/group/:groupId/edit" component={EditGroupModal} />
</Route>
```

The `HomePage` doesn't actually exist but I can handle loading the groups from local storage and then forcing a redirect inside of this component. Just not sure its the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

React Router V4 [has a](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) `render` property that can be assigned to a function. Within that function, you could perform whatever operation or conditional you want to.

Your route should look something like:

```
<Route exact path="/groups" render={() => (
    <Redirect to=`/groups/${id}` />
  )
)}/>
```

The setback I see in your specific case is accessing the `id` itself since the group route is `/groups`. If you already use the `onEnter()` function, then chances are you could use the `render()` API.

Comment: Ah, I think this looks promising and should allow me to accomplish what I want. Thank you!

Comment: @yourfavorite  Awesome! let's know what ends up working for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use a `<Redirect />` in your HomePage component. The [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) have some examples, but once you have got the group ID, your `render()` function can just

```
return (
    <Redirect to=`/group/${id}` />
);
```

Comment: Thanks Tony. This is what I was planning on doing inside of the HomePage module. However I was wondering if there was a better pattern that didn't require the HomePage module but could instead handle it all inside of the file where I have my Routes.